# Trouble writing a span to a pdf with pypdf

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, pypdf

I am using pypdf python library to create a way to lock a pdf to only one mac address. So that only one person can open the pdf and after that it will be locked, it won't be able to open on other devices. But I am having trouble writing the mac address of the device to the span. what am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import pypdf
import uuid

# Get MAC address of device
mac_address = hex(uuid.getnode())

# Create JavaScript to be embedded in PDF
js_code = f""" 
var mac_address_span = this.getField("mac-address");
if (mac_address_span == null) {{
    var new_span = this.addField("mac-address", "int", {mac_address}, [0, 0, 0, 0]);
    
    app.alert("MAC address span created with value: " + {mac_address});    
}} else {{
    app.alert('whyyy2');
    if (mac_address_span.get("/V") == "{mac_address}") {{
        app.alert("MAC address span exists with matching value: " + mac_address_span.value);
    }} else {{
        app.alert("MAC address span exists with non-matching value: " + mac_address_span.value);
        this.closeDoc(true);
    }}
}}
"""

# Open PDF
with open("example.pdf", mode="rb") as f:
    pdf_reader = pypdf.PdfReader(f)
    pdf_writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()

 
    # Add JavaScript action to document open event
    js_name = 'mac-address.js'
    js_action = pdf_writer.add_js(js_code)
    
    if js_action:
        pdf_writer._add_object(js_action)
    else:
        print("Failed to create JavaScript action object")


    # Add all pages to output PDF
   # for page in range(pdf_reader.pages()):
    #    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

    for page in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
        pdf_writer.add_page(pdf_reader.pages[page])

    # Save output PDF
    with open("output.pdf", mode="wb") as output_file:
        pdf_writer.write(output_file)

# Open output PDF
if os.name == 'nt':  # for Windows OS
    os.startfile("output.pdf")
else:  # for Mac OS
    subprocess.call(["open", "output.pdf"])
```